# How to get different Spring label message on the same screen for different context of application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

I have different contexts (say A and B) in an application which uses the same screen for both the context, but i have display different label names on the screen fields.

Resource bundle is as follows.

For context A, `sample.code=Text From Application A` goes into `sampleA.properties`

For context B, `sample.code=Text From Application B` goes into `sampleB.properties`

And, I can differentiate the context from the session attribute. In that case, how could i override the `Spring MessageTag` and read the message with respect to context set?

JSP: `<spring:message code="sample.code" />`

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register separate [ResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) for different servlet context configuration

eg. on your AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    // root context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(RootConfig.class); // configuration class for root context

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // dispatcher servlet 1
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext1 = 
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webContext1.setParent(rootContext);
    webContext1.register(WebConfig1.class); // configuration class for servlet 1

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher1 =
    servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher1", new DispatcherServlet(webContext1));
    dispatcher1.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher1.addMapping("/subcontext1");

    // dispatcher servlet 2
   AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext2 = 
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webContext1.setParent(rootContext);
    webContext1.register(WebConfig2.class); // configuration class for servlet 1

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher2 =
    servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher2", new DispatcherServlet(webContext2));
    dispatcher2.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher2.addMapping("/subcontext1");

}
```

**WebConfig1**

```
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource configureResourceBundleMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resource.setBasename("sampleA");
    return resource;
}
```

**WebConfig2**

```
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource configureResourceBundleMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resource.setBasename("sampleB");
    return resource;
}
```